# Receiving file on Android

Tags: javascript, android, rest

I have a Javascript code on a server that is sending out a text file using the function sendFile.
With curl from a terminal, all OK, I can see the content of the file sent.
I need to do the same from an Android app (I didn't designed the app from scratch so I have to use the same architecture/structure).

The Android app is supposed to receive from the server a text file (sent using sendFile).
I did set up a model for the data received and I imagined the content received was a List (of String).
I end up with an exception :

> retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
>   at line 1 column 1 path $

How I can structure my model to receive an object ?
My model right now is like this :

```
public class UsedModel {

    public List<String> msg;
}
```

It seems the sendFile is not sending out a Json format.
A curl call like this (from a linux box) :

```
curl --request GET  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' server_address/api/getApiWithSendFile | json_pp
```

basically returns

> malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom,
>   at character offset 0 (before "text received from server...") at
>   /usr/bin/json_pp5.18 line 45.

So it doesn't seems I'm receiving a Json ... is that the problem ?

Any suggestion ?

I would like to avoid to modify the javascript server side in some other ways.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting the error:

> retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
>   at line 1 column 1 path $

means that **you are getting a response that is not a [Json Object](https://www.json.org/)**, be sure your response returns something like `{...}`, begins with `{` left brace and ends with `}` right brace.

Comment: Thanks ... basically from what I can see, when preparing to receive the code is setting up to wait for an Object.
I though it was because I did pass the model as data, i.e. :
@GET("/api/getApiWithSendFile") UsedModel getTheFile();

But also changing in :
@GET("/api/getApiWithSendFile") String getTheFile();

it ends up expecting an object ... need to figure out how to change that since apparently I'm receiving just a string from the server.
Thanks